# Hibernate cfg.xml - unable to make jdbc connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

i am trying to strip out my old database code to replace with hibernate. I have done most of the ground work however I seem to be running in to some issues when trying to connect to the database

My hibernate cfg.xml looks as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mariadb://ip:port/schema?autoReconnect=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="Card.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The connection details are a straight copy paste job from my original (working) non hibernate application so they are definitely correct. is there something wrong with the format of my config file? The exception thrown is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:mariadb://ip:port/schema?autoReconnect=true]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at com.swiped.cards.HibernateUtil.configureSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at com.swiped.cards.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at com.swiped.cards.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

I am also connected to this database using sql workbench so I'm sure the details are correct.

Thanks

Comment: In your connection string, you have "mariadb" for the protocol/dialect. You said that you are using MySQL, so replacing mariadb with mysql would maybe do the trick.

Comment: they should be interchangeable right?

Comment: I dont know anything about mariadb but when you use MySQL, you should of course use its protocol. Just replace the word.

Comment: well this was the answer i believe, please accept my apologies and if you can provide an answer i will accept and up vote :p

Comment: Did it work? If so, I guess I quickly post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong connection string. Your configuration uses the MariaDB protocol/dialect.

To get your database connection working, just replace "mariadb" with "mysql".

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some variables in your template file, it must be something like that:
I set the variables you must change to Uppercase, so it is more easy for you to see.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:**mysql**://**HEREYOUPUTIP:HERETHEPORT/YOURSCHEMA**?autoReconnect=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">**THEUSEROFYOURDB**</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">**YOURDBPASSOWRD**</property>

        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="Card.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: This answer doesnt make sense because the OT stated that he uses the correct credentials.

Comment: @MrPixelDream. But he lied, since he used mariadb instead of mysql in the URL. This doesn't deserve a downvote, IMHO.

Comment: Even though you are more or less correct (when I say credentials, I mean username and password; not the connection string) this answer isnt correct anyways because there is the wrong connection string used again.

Comment: My fault, sorry, just copyed the example Biscuit128 used and changed the things i thought was wrong, i'm going to edit it to mysql. Btw, i don't know if it was necessary a downvote.

Comment: Well, now that you corrected your answer, I did remove the downvote. But for me, the downvote was required because your answer was simply wrong. It didn't help to solve the problem. But of course, now your answer is correct.